# How to using animation in react native

Tags: javascript, android, animation, react-native

I am creating an app that will generate random numbers. 
The problem now is how can I add a animation effect when generating the number. 
The best example is like slot machine, where each of number will be rotating vertically.

Where should I start? 
Unlike react js, where I can manipulate the DOM element with js. I don't know how this can be achieve in react native.

Comment: The recommended way is to use the Animated api. Check out this post that walks through how to implement the api: https://medium.com/the-react-native-log/react-native-animations-using-the-animated-api-ebe8e0669fae#.x8kwh4m0i

Answer (score 0):

Look at this example. [Slot machine](https://github.com/Sing-Li/react-native-Game1) or [this](https://github.com/amarcher/TopDog)